# Let $K$ be a field in $A$. If $a_1,\dots, a_n\in A$ prove there exists a unique ring morphism $\phi:K[x_1,\dots, x_n]\to A$ such that $\phi(x_i)=a_i$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field in $A$. If $a_1,\dots, a_n\in A$, prove there exists a unique ring morphism $\phi:K[x_1,\dots, x_n]\to A$, such that $\phi(x_i)=a_i$

I'm actually not entirely sure I understand the question. From my understanding since $K\in A$ and $K[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ has coefficients in $K$, I can define a ring morphism $\psi:K[x_1,\dots, x_n]\to K$ such that for $k_1,...k_n \in K$, $\psi(x_i)=k_i$ and then define $f:K\to A$ as $f(k_i)=a_i$

Then for $f\circ\psi$, I prove that this is a ring morphism. But would the uniqueness part be proving that  $\phi=f\circ\psi$ or proving something else?

Comment: I don't see the use of writing  $\phi $ as the composition of two functions. You can define it directly via $f (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto f (a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$.

Comment: I did the composition to explicitly have the function of $\phi$, and prove its existence. Since the units and zero of $K$ are also in $K[x_1,\dots, k_n]$. I have to send them somewhere in $A$ as well. 

I'm sorry but I'm not understanding the $f$ above you defined.

Comment: To say it in a slightly different way:

You could start with assuming that $\phi(x_i) = a_i$. Then to show that $\phi$ gives a unique ring morphism, it's enough to show that on any polynomial $f= \Sigma k_I x^I$, $\phi$ is determined. Since it's a ring homomorphism, $\phi(f) = \Sigma \phi(k_Ix^I)) = \Sigma \phi(k_I)\phi(x^I)= \Sigma \phi(k_i)a^I$. So it would be enough to show that $\phi(k)$ is determined for any $k \in K$.

But this is false right? Consider $\mathbb{C}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, with $a=0$. I have both identity and complex conjugation available to me.

Comment: Got it now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question answered in comments.